# React-native: How to convert byte array(Buffer data) to Bit(Binary data)

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I am new in react native and i develop app with Bluetooth device so hear, Bluetooth device send a data and my app received those data in buffer,

My problem is,

How to convert this buffer data in binary format ? then after this binary data convert in decimal.

Please check my below code.

```
bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
       "BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic",
       ({ value, peripheral, characteristic, service }) => {

         // Buffer data return from Bluetooth device
         const buffer = Buffer.from(value); 
         console.lgo("buffer >> "+buffer) //[161,52]             

         return dispatch({
           type: BLUETOOTH_TYPE.READ_DATA,
           weight: sensorData
         });
       }
     );
```

Hear buffer data is like [161, 52], how convert in binary format ? and then how convert this binary data in decimal ?

Output for [161,52] is 306.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer is a binary format. You can get a number out of it differently, depends on how it was written.

If it's a float you can use   `buffer.readFloatBE()` or   `.readFloatLE()` . If it's double - `.readDoubleBE()` or `.readDoubleLE()`.

You can read about all the types here https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readdoublebe_offset

Answer (score 0):

finally i got solution,

My device is return data in byte array, so i want to read it(catch in buffer) and convert in binary format and finally this binary data convert in decimal value.

```
 const buffer = Buffer.from(deviceResponseInByteArray);
             const byteToBit = buffer.readUInt16BE(0).toString(2);
             const batteryPowerInBinary = byteToBit.substring(2, 3);
             const weightInBinary = byteToBit.substring(4);
             var weightInDecimal = parseInt(weightInBinary, 2).toString(
               10
             );
```